# Position icons in the div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to position the icons in the left and right of div.

But Its not working as you can see in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L9rwhuor/2/

The left icon is not at the center in vertical terms, and the right icon is in the bottom right not at the center.

Do you know why is not working properly?

Html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box-left">
        <div class="box-left-up">
            <h2>Test</h2>
            <div class="text">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" style="float:left; margin-top:15px;"></i>
                <p>test 1</p>
                <p>test 2</p>
                <p>test 2</p>
                <p>test 2</p>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="clear:both;float:right; margin-top:15px"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px; 
}

#container .text{
    text-align: center;
}

#container h2{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
}
#container .box-left{
    float: left;
    width:  480px;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother with floats in this situation. This is a good place for absolute positioning.

```
.text {
   position: relative;
}

.right-button {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 15px;
}    

.left-button {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9rwhuor/3/

Answer (score 0):

change order of elements

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" style="float:left; margin-top:15px;"></i>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="float:right; margin-top:15px"></i>    
<p>test 1</p>
<p>test 2</p>
<p>test 2</p>
<p>test 2</p>
```